# SQL multiple columns that has one column as relation

Tags: sql

I have a table named `engrams` with columns

```
mat_name1, mat_name2, mat_name3, mat_name4
```

that has a relation with table `resources` on column `id`.

I have this SQL statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM engrams 
INNER JOIN resources ON engrams.mat_name1 = resources.id
```

How do I add the other `mat_name` columns with `resources.id` and how do I echo the column `res_name` from `resources` table for every `mat_name`?

[image: engrams table]

[image: resources table]

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you need. Seeing your sentence, you will get all columns in both tables (engrams and resources), isn't that what you are looking? If not, can you provide an example output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` your `engrams` table to the `resources` table 4 times, once for each material name. Since you will have similar column names from each `JOIN` of the `resources` table, you will probably need to use aliases to distinguish them in your application framework:

```
SELECT e.name,
       e.description,
       e.mat_name1, r1.res_name AS res_name1, r1.description AS res_descr1,
       e.mat_name2, r2.res_name AS res_name2, r2.description AS res_descr2,
       e.mat_name3, r3.res_name AS res_name3, r3.description AS res_descr3,
       e.mat_name4, r4.res_name AS res_name4, r4.description AS res_descr4
FROM engrams e
LEFT JOIN resources r1 ON r1.id = e.mat_name1
LEFT JOIN resources r2 ON r2.id = e.mat_name2
LEFT JOIN resources r3 ON r3.id = e.mat_name3
LEFT JOIN resources r4 ON r4.id = e.mat_name4
```

Comment: your example is working as i need but i have to select all columns, how do i deal with that?

Comment: @BogdanGalan I've updated the query to fetch all non-`id` values. If you want the `id` values as well it should be pretty obvious how to add them.

Comment: i have 23 columns in total, do i have to add them all like in your example (e.name, e.description, etc.)?

Comment: @BogdanGalan you just need to manually select values by name and give them aliases (as I have done) where there can be overlapping names (I.e. all the values from the `resources` table). You could replace all the `e.name` etc. with a single `e.*` to simplify.

Comment: also if you often query against this data, you may consider building out a `view` so you're not having to build this query out each time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then all you need to do is add `OR` statements to your `ON` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM engrams 
INNER JOIN resources 
ON engrams.mat_name1 = resources.id
    or engrams.mat_name2 = resources.id
    or engrams.mat_name3 = resources.id
    or engrams.mat_name4 = resources.id
```

As is that query will return all values for both engrames and resources. If you don't want everything, just explicity define which you do such as:

```
SELECT resources.res_name, engrams.mat_name1, engrams.mat_name2, engrams.mat_name3,engrams.mat_name4
FROM engrams 
INNER JOIN resources 
ON engrams.mat_name1 = resources.id
    or engrams.mat_name2 = resources.id
    or engrams.mat_name3 = resources.id
    or engrams.mat_name4 = resources.id
```

If "echo the column" means something else, you'll have to include some example output or something.